# It is possible to create your own bit sequence and then send it to the network card of your choice?

Tags: networking, network-programming, protocols, network-protocols, nic

For example, is it possible to send this "11110000 00001111" sequence alone, without any protocol encapsulating it, or even Ethernet or IP in order to implement a different protocol for my local network?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your goal. You just want to send a sequence without even using Ethernet 802.3 protocol? If that is your question, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @rodolk Yes, that's right, is Ethernet mandatory systematically?  The OS doesn't give us a way to control what is transmitted to the NIC?

Comment: I really think it's not possible. Usually the 802.3 protocol is already programmed in the NIC.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the sequence without IP headers through an 802.3 frame. But I think MAC protocol already comes in the NIC with some logic also in the device driver.